# How to speed the process time of a function that finds combinations?

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, optimization

I am working on this problem where I need to find all of the combinations of the purchase items in a .csv file that equal a total. The purchase items can be positive and negative. When I run my code with practice data I can get the correct answer but when I use the real data which has hundreds of purchases it runs forever. I am wondering how to speed up the processing time of the following code.

```
import decimal
import pandas
import datetime

df = pandas.read_csv('negative_test.csv')
print(df)

# Index are the keys of the dictonary
index_list = list(df.index)

# Values are the values of the dictonary
values = df["Purchase"].to_list()
target = df["Target"].to_list()[0]
print(target)

def sanitize_values(list1):
    sanitized_list = []
    for item in list1:
        sanitized_list.append(float(item.replace(",","")))
    return sanitized_list

def merge(list1, list2):

    merged_list = [(list1[i], list2[i]) for i in range(0, len(list1))]
    return merged_list

merged_tuples = merge(index_list,sanitize_values(values))

def sum_tuples(tuples):
    s = 0
    for i in range(len(tuples)):
        s += tuples[i][1]
        #s += round(tuples[i][1],2)

    return s

def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[], s=0, progress=0):
    if(len(partial) > 0):
        s += partial[len(partial)-1][1]
    #s = sum_tuples(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if round(s,2) == round(target,2):
        print ((partial, target))

    if len(numbers) == 0:
        return

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        #hacked in progress bar
        if(len(partial) == 0):
            progress += 1
            printDateTime()
            print("progress: " + str(progress))


        #print("Starting from: " + str(i) + " Numbers: " + str(numbers) + "\n len: " + str(len(partial)) + "partial: " + str(partial))
        n = numbers[i][1]
        #n = round(numbers[i][1],2)
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        # print(remaining)

        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [numbers[i]], s, progress)

def printDateTime():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print ("Current date and time : ")
    print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    printDateTime()
    subset_sum(merged_tuples,target)
    printDateTime()
```

Comment: If you want to generate a list with trillions of elements in it, you have to do trillions of operations.  (And trillions is a severe underestimate of how many combinations there are going to be here.) What are you trying to do, and how can you do it without actually generating the full list?

Comment: I'll give a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. Let's say for instance I have a purchase list that has the items [1,2,3,4] and the total I'm looking for is 6$. I need to find the different combinations of the items that equal the total and each item in the list can only be used once. The solutions would be [1,2,3] and [2,4]. This is a simplified solution. The actual data I am working with has negative and positive numbers and decimals.

Comment: I know what you are asking for.  But if you have a list of 200 elements, there are `2^200` subsets.  If only one in a trillion of them adds up to your target sum, there are about `10^48` lists in your solution.  That's roughly one solution per atom that is part of the Earth.  As a practical matter it is impossible to construct a list that long.

Comment: So what you are trying to do is actually **impossible**.  But presumably you are doing this for a reason.  If you're willing to describe the task that lead you to try to do this, there is a good chance that we can find a way to do it without having to generate that list.

Comment: I am trying to code this for my Dad who is an accountant. Let's say for instance he has a cheque paying Joe for $5962.22 for say 12 invoices. However, he has 150 total invoices from Joe. How do you find out which invoices that $5962.22 paid? What is the max amount of items in a CSV that I could compute?

Comment: Since there may be many possible answers, what is your preference?  The most recent invoices?  The oldest invoices?  The most invoices?  The fewest invoices?